# Is there a method to create a persistent variable in my Django view function?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm currently grabbing a variable `'my_var'` via GET when my view function is called, as shown.  I need to query by this variable in my POST method.

```
def article_delete_view(request, pk):
    my_var = request.GET.get('my_var') #GET THE VARIABLE from referring data-url
    obj = Listing.objects.get(type=type) # I could query here if I wanted (illustration only)
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        article.delete()
        data['form_is_valid'] = True
        articles = Article.objects.all()
        obj = Listing.objects.get(name=my_var) #THIS DOES NOT WORK, since 'type' is not passed on submit.
        context = {'articles':articles, 'obj':obj}
        data['article_table'] = render_to_string('article_table.html', context)
    else:
        context = {'article':article}
        data['html_form'] = render_to_string('article_delete.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Is there a best-practice way to make that variable persist when POST is called on a submit?  I know declaring a global is a bad idea.  Thought about writing it to memory (attached to article) but that feels like a hack.  Appending it to the `pk` argument then splitting it out feels even worse.  Yuck.  I could get my `<input>` method to pass `my_var` but to do so I'd have to refactor a lot of other things to make it happen.  Are django session variables the answer here?  Any perspective is helpful.  Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE & SOLUTION:**

So to contextualize, the issue here is that I want to query a specific model instance within a view that does not have that model instance info (pk or id) passed to it as an argument. I can `GET` that variable through the `data-url` that fires the view, but only once.  It was not usable in `POST`, or on any subsequent call to `article_delete_view`.

Imagine you're trying to make a peanut butter sandwich, but you can only retrieve one item at a time from the cupboard. You get the peanut butter on the first visit to the cupboard, but when you open the cupboard again to get the bread, the peanut butter *disappears*.  Session variables turned out to be a solution for saving the peanut butter, you know, like a little shelf.  A rolling wheelie shelf.  Anyway:

```
def article_delete_view(request, pk):
    my_var = request.GET.get('my_var')
    if my_var is not None: #This prevents my_var from being lost subsequent function calls
        request.session['session_var'] = my_var = request.GET.get('my_var') # create session variable
    else:
        pass
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        article.delete()
        data['form_is_valid'] = True
        articles = Article.objects.all()
        session_var = request.session.get('session_var', None) # grab the session variable here
        obj = Listing.objects.get(name=session_var) # NOW THIS WORKS!
        context = {'articles':articles, 'obj':obj}
        data['article_table'] = render_to_string('article_table.html', context)
    else:
        context = {'article':article}
        data['html_form'] = render_to_string('article_delete.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

The `if` that follows getting my_var prevents the session variable from being written as null on each subsequent call to the view, since `GET` only gets the variable the first time. If anyone is curious where that `session_var` is actually coming from, here's the source (obj.slug):

```
<button type="button" data-url="{% url 'article_delete' article.id %}?my_var={{obj.slug}}">Name</button>
```

I'm using GET to grab it from a template where it's in scope, so I can query with it in `article_delete_view`.  Passing it in as a URL parameter did not work, since that pattern doesn't match anything in my app.  So far this is working great.  If anybody has any other ideas and/or can tell me why this is a bad idea, please post.

Comment: type is a python builtin, don't use type as your variables name.

Comment: `request.GET` is a dictionary-like object containing all given HTTP GET parameters also known as query parameters. It's not a method. `request.GET` is also available in post requests.

Comment: Type is not the actual variable. I'll edit.

Comment: I ended up solving this with session variables and it works just fine.  However, still hoping someone might post other ideas.

Comment: can you post what you did using the session in question description as an update?